# Still list parents' house as permanent residence while renting apartment

Tags: taxes, income-tax, new-york, new-jersey, primary-residence

I just graduated from college and plan on renting an apartment in NYC to commute to work in NJ. However, I've been listing my parents' home in New Jersey as my permanent residence. Can I still show my parents' home as my permanent residence while the rental apartment as a secondary residence? Do I need to live in New Jersey for more than half a year? I'd like to avoid paying NYC city tax on top of NY state income tax.

tl:dr; Work in New Jersey, lived in Jersey, planning on renting in NYC, don't want to pay city tax by listing parents' house as residence.

Comment: If you don't want to pay NYC, your option is not to live in the city. Commute in  from Westchester, or Jersey. Of course, the commute has its own costs.

Comment: If this was possible/allowed, I'm pretty sure over half the NYC residents wouldn't be paying taxes.

Answer (score 4):

You can always lie and say you live in a different place, no-one but you can prevent you from doing stupid things. You need to remember that tax fraud is a criminal offense and you may end up in jail and/or with a huge tax penalty bill **when** you get caught.

You will get caught because tax fraud has no statute of limitations periods, and there will always be people who know you lied on your taxes and it only takes one to tip the agency off for a reward.

Comment: I... I mean... Loss of words is best way to describe my current state. Are you really recommending for him to commit a crime?

Comment: How on Earth did you read my warning about jail time and penalties as "recommending to commit a crime"???

Comment: Because it was prefixed with "You can always lie and say you live in a different place." posted as an answer rather than "What you suggest is a crime, it's wrong and you will go to jail".

Comment: Irony, alas, often does not come across well in electronic communication, especially when some of the readers are not native speakers of the language. My own style leans strongly that direction, and I've had to learn to either make it _very_ obvious (which makes it much less fun) or suppress it as much as possible. I hate to be a spoilsport, but rewriting to be more explicit would probably be wise. Sigh.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul There is nothing wrong with the answer and stack is not a place for legal advice anyway. And often the more elaborate approach is preferred over the "for dummies" one. Reader beware, please read the answer in full **and** take your time to interpret and understand the text. Also as Keshalm pointed out, non-native english speakers usually form sentences in unusual (from a NES perspective) ways.

Comment: You say "tax fraud is a criminal offense and you may end up in jail" and then "tax fraud has no statute of limitations periods". Let's clarify a few things. There is criminal tax evasion (which you can go to jail for) and civil tax evasion (which you can only be fined for). It's civil tax evasion that has no statute of limitations. Criminal tax evasion can only be prosecuted up to six years after the offense. So you can't go to jail for tax evasion that happened more than six years ago (unless it was related to continued evasion that crossed the six-year barrier).